# What IDE's can be configured to auto-format JavaScript according to Google's JavaScript Style Guide?

Tags: javascript, ide, google-closure-library

I'm trying to conform my code to [Google's JavaScript Style Guide](http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javascriptguide.xml) but some of the requirements require very granular control that I haven’t been able to achieve in Eclipse, IntelliJ, etc. For instance, within block comments the @fileoverview description should wrap at 80 columns but not indent, while the @param description should wrap but indent 4 spaces. Just curious if there are IDE’s that let you run a format command to conform with Google’s standards.  The closest I've come is Eclipse for JavaScript developers.

Comment: Looks like it might require patching the JSDT Eclipse plugin to get the additional options required for using the native 'Format' function, but it's fairly easy to at least add [Closure Linter](http://code.google.com/closure/utilities/) as an 'External Tool' in Eclipse, so you can run the analyzer (gjslint) and the auto-fixer (fixjsstyle) against the current .js file.  I'll post the details later.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using Visual Studio 2010 code reformatting feature (ctrl k + d) and these code snippets:

[Annotated, Google Closure Javascript Compiler - Visual Studio Snippets](http://www.picnet.com.au/blogs/Guido/post/2010/06/03/Annotated-Google-Closure-Javascript-Compiler-Visual-Studio-Snippets.aspx)

Free version of Visual Studio is here http://www.microsoft.com/express/Web/

Answer (score 0):

I am using IntelliJ 10.5 and check my coding style via closure-linter and everything works fine. Sometimes I still have to intervene so that the linebreaks make more sense.

Greetings,

Jan

Comment: Can you please tell me how I can configure intellij to use closure Linter